# How to Change Label Name From Paypal

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm Working on Woo-commerce Payment Integration.
I want to change name of Label - **shipping and handling**  to **shipping**.
Please find Below screen shot. [image]

I have find on this link that it's coming from NVP Field and SOAP Field  : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

NVP fields are :

- PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPPINGAMT  (For Shipping)
- PAYMENTREQUEST_n_HANDLINGAMT (For Handling)

SOAP fields are :

- ShippingTotal(For Shipping)
- HandlingTotal(For Handling)

But i can't find out this fields in woo-commerce plugin.
So how can i change name of this label? is it possible ?
Let me know if any furthure information is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to adjust that particular label.

Comment: @AndrewAngell. Thank you brother for the reply. Have you found it from any particular link ? can you please share that link with me ?

Comment: @AndrewAngell. Ohk great. please give answer so i can accept it. 
 after seeing your profile no links are necessary now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to adjust that particular label.

You may want to check what API version you're using in your API calls, though.  PayPal has been pushing out new versions of the Express Checkout pages that are newer and have different phrasing you may like better.  Make sure you're not using an old API version and you should be seeing the newer pages more than this version you're showing here.